# Add invitation functionality to Laravels authentication controller

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I am using Laravels normal authentication functionality with `RegisterController` and the default views that are included. I have modified the `RegisterController@create` method to create a related model called `Home` to the `User`. Although a `Home` can have several `User` relations.

After signup, the `User` automatically have a `Home` related to them. The user should now be able to invite new users to join their `Home`. All the logic around the invites are solved, but I was wondering what the best solution for registering the invited user is.

Currently I have created a `InviteController` with a `acceptInvite` method that registers the new `User` related to the existing `Home`. But I really want to reuse the `RegisterController@create` method instead of having to maintain two registration processes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just check the existence of an `invitation` param (or something like that) to decide if you need to create a new user with a brand new `Home` or create this new user and let it join the already created `Home`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear... The user you want to invite to HOME are they registered users? if yes

All you need is a many to many relationship using a pivot table.

If the user you want to add to HOME is a new user and not already register on your app, just send them a mail with link to your register page, and let then use the RegisterController@create

Hope this help:)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.

The invitation goes out to a not already registered user.